# counting number of comparisons in quicksort Gives stackoverflow

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I am trying to write a program that counts the number of comparisons in a quicksort program.

This is my code

```
package algo_quicksort;

public class Algo_quicksort {

    public static int partition(int[]A,int p,int r){
        int x=A[p];
        int i=p+1;
        int temp;
        for(int j=p+1;j<r;j++){
            if(A[j]<x){//if A[j] is bigger than the pivot do nothing 
                temp=A[j];
                A[j]=A[i];
                A[i]=temp;
                i++;
            }
        }
        temp=A[p];
        A[p]=A[i-1];
        A[i-1]=temp;
        return i-1;
    }
    public static long quickSort(int[]A,int startPos,int length){
        if(length==1){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            if(startPos<length){
            int pivot= partition(A,0,length);
          quickSort(A,startPos,pivot+1);
          quickSort(A, pivot+2,length); 
            return length-startPos-1;
        }
            else{
                return 0;
            }
    }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[]={3,2,4};
        System.out.println("# of comparisons is: " +quickSort(a,0,a.length));

        System.out.println("A[] after quicksort is: ");

        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            System.out.print(a[i]+"  ");
        }

    }
}
```

it works perfectly for any array of size 3 or less, but if it is any bigger than that it gives me a stackoverflow exception at the recursive call I tried debugging my code but could not figure out where it's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have a recursive function, *quickSort()*.

Usually when you get a stackoverflow condition with recursive methods it is because you either  aren't getting the "end" condition right (or when to stop) or your input parameter is not correct.

I experimented with your code by tweaking the input parameter and got the following result.

```
int a[]={3,2,4,5};    
System.out.println("# of comparisons is: " +quickSort(a,0,a.length -1));
//changed from a.length to a.length - 1
```

**Result**

# of comparisons is: 2
A[] after quicksort is: 
2  3  4  5

---

However I do not believe this is the fix because if I change the array to "int a[]={5,3,2,4};", then the stackoverflow error occurs again :(

This leads me to believe that there is something wrong in your end condition...somewhere in *quickSort()*.  Check wikipedia or stackoverflow and validate your code with a correct implementation.

---

So after writing some tests for this, it seems that your implementation of *quicksort* is incorrect.  It's returning zero if the length is 1.  However if I pass it an array of length one with the value of 5, zero is returned whereas I would expect 5.

This means that your stopping condition is incorrect.  After some googling, I found the following:

1. First = Last; only one element in array means sorted.
2. First > Last; no values in array means sorted.

Then you need to take a look at your arguments for *quicksort*.  I don't believe you need start position or array length.  It should just need the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have four elements in the array, the first pass is 3 comparisons + 2 in the second pass + 1 in the third pass, or 6 deep.  You must be pushing something onto the stack for each comparison.  This suggests your stack is 8 levels deep given the other code calling subroutines, however stacks these days are usually done with stack pointers and might be thousands of entries long. [JVM Organization](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/modules/lectures/co/jvm/organization.htm) explains the overall structure.